# Error trying to insert payment to database

Tags: sql, database, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

As I am trying to input the total payroll (Input Gaji) to a database, it gives an error, and the welcome label keeps increasing by one every time I press "Hitung Total Gaji" (this is to calculate the total payroll).

[Error that I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLCav.png)

**The Code** [(File on Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q7Fs6V5FBP-Hdvfo7bBBRJPDUINMVSkX/view?usp=sharing)**:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Users : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int Gaji1;
    String ValueGaji1;
    int Waktu1;
    String ValueWaktu1;
    int TGK;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            WelcomeLabel.Text += Session["New"].ToString();

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select [Nama],[GPJ],[NIK],[Jabatan],[Gaji] from UserData where Username='" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);

            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                NamaLabel.Text = reader["Nama"].ToString();
                JabatanLabel.Text = reader["Jabatan"].ToString();
                NIKLabel.Text = reader["NIK"].ToString();
                GPJLabel.Text += reader["GPJ"].ToString();
            }
            conn.Close();

        }
        else Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["New"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select [Nama],[GPJ],[NIK],[Jabatan],[Gaji] from UserData where Username='" + Session["New"].ToString() + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);

        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            NamaLabel.Text = reader["Nama"].ToString();
            JabatanLabel.Text = reader["Jabatan"].ToString();
            NIKLabel.Text = reader["NIK"].ToString();
            GPJLabel.Text = reader["GPJ"].ToString();

            ValueGaji1 = reader["GPJ"].ToString();
            Gaji1 = int.Parse(ValueGaji1);

            ValueWaktu1 = WKTB.Text.ToString();
            Waktu1 = int.Parse(ValueWaktu1);

            TGK = Waktu1 * Gaji1;
            TGLabel.Text = TGK.ToString() ;
        }

        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string InsertQuery = "insert into UserData (Gaji,WK) values (@Gaji1,@Waktu1)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gaji1", TGLabel.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Waktu1", WKTB.Text);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: "+ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to include the error and code into your post instead of separately as images. You wouldn't want someone to have to type up all that code to try and reproduce the problem, or suggest a fix. Copy and paste it into your post and use the `{ }` button or CTRL + K to format it as code.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru i have tried using the format code but it didn't work that is why i uploaded the code in notepad to google drive and it is copy paste able

Comment: I've embedded it for you, but generally speaking it's good to provide as much relevant detail as possible when asking a question so people don't have to spend a lot of energy trying to figure out what's wrong. That will increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you did not supply a value for the column `NIK` which is defined as `NOT NULL` in the table.

Comment: before i put the 2nd button which is to put the data into database for Gaji(Pay),and Waktu Kerja(Work time) it all works fine

it is supposed to read NIK value from database,not to insert it into database

Comment: You are inserting a new row to the table with `insert into UserData...`